# Why is my Android Studio application working slowly on smartphones?

Tags: java, android, mobile-application

I am a beginner programmer on Android, and when I create an app and install it on my real phone or other phones, it works very slowly (I don't talk about emulators).

- The size of file is only 3 MB
- This happens to all applications that i make
- I cleaned the cache and the project before building
  The devices that I installed the application on :HTC 630, Samsung Galaxy S7, and Samsung Duos J1.
  any idea?

  ```
          <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  ```

  <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:background="@drawable/bcc">

  ```
   <LinearLayout
       android:layout_width="0dp"
       android:layout_height="495dp"
       android:orientation="vertical"

       app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
       app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent">


       <TextView
           android:id="@+id/textView2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edge"
           android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/edge"
           android:text="Enter your name:"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="@dimen/fsize"
           android:textStyle="bold"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

       <EditText
           android:id="@+id/editText2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_margin="@dimen/edge"
           android:ems="10"
           android:inputType="textPersonName"
           android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
           android:textSize="@dimen/fsize"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />

       <Button
           android:id="@+id/button2"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/edge"
           android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/edge"

           android:onClick="nxt"
           android:text="Next"
           android:textSize="@dimen/fsize"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="38dp"
           tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp" />
   </LinearLayout>
  ```

  </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>

java code:

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void nxt(View view) {

        EditText name =(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        Intent txtint= new Intent(this,Main2Activity.class);
        Bundle b = new Bundle();

        b.putString("user",name.getText().toString());
        txtint.putExtras(b);


        startActivity(txtint);
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You need to give some information to go on. You are likely doing something poorly in the code.

Comment: You first activity is light, no risk there. Never used `android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout` but I would not think this would kill the perfs. So what are you doing in the second activity and of course, what is slow ? And what about in the emulator ?

Comment: Buttons, loading activities, writing, everything is slow..
someone told me that the problem may be caused because of Memory Heap .. but i don't really know how to change it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved the problem.. i had a mistake in resize of background (to fit screens).